# Opposite side of an "Any" attribute

Tags: .net, nhibernate, castle-activerecord

I have a class that looks like this

```
public class Comment
{
[Any(typeof(int), MetaType=typeof(int),
    TypeColumn="RecordTypeID",
    IdColumn="RecordID",
    Cascade=CascadeEnum.SaveUpdate)]
[Any.MetaValue(1, typeof(News))]
[Any.MetaValue(2, typeof(Feature))]
public IContentItem Item
{get;set;}
}
```

How do I Create the Many on the News/Feature side??

```
public class News : IContentItem
{
[ManyRelationship]
public IList<Comment> Comments
{get;set;}
}

public class Feature : IContentItem
{
[ManyRelationship]
public IList<Comment> Comments
{get;set;}
}
```

Anyone got any ideas on this please I have been mucking around with this for a few days. By the way the answer is not HasManyToAny

Answer (score 1):

This post has exactly what you want: http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2010/11/conform-any-to-many.html, only it uses full NH, mapped with ConfORM.

You might be able to generate the XML and refactor it into ActiveRecord attributes. Or, you can move forward to NH + ConfORM :-)

Comment: This does look like what I want I just have no idea how to configure it with ActiveRecord, do you have any clues or point me in the right direction?

Comment: @Paul: you'll use `HasMany` with an `Inverse` an a `Where` attribute (or however that's called in ActiveRecord) matching MetaValue of each IContentItem